# Mean value- Law of large numbers

Tags: probability

Let $N_n$ be the number of occurrences of 5 and 6 in n throws for a fair dice, using the mean square- law of large numbers i want to show that as ${n \to \infty}$

${N_n/n \to 1/3}$ in mean square

My attempt: Now $N_n$ can take values of 0,1,2....n and I get the mean for N_n to be

$
\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(2/3)^m(1/3)^kk$ where $m$ is $n-k$, I cant seem to evaluate this arithmethic-binomial sum and most likely thought about the problem wrong.

Comment: To apply the LLN, one must have a sum of i.i.d. random variables somewhere. Where is such a sum in your context?

Comment: @Did this was all given in the question, I think I have to come up with the i.i.d random variables, which im struggling to